# SWift Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 "Cannot Complete Action "NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later.,

Tags: swift

I am facing some problems with AVPlayer and AVMutableComposition.
My app is a small video editor that use AVMutableComposition and Custom Video instruction (AVVideoCompositing) with AVVideoCompositionInstructionProtocol

Everything works great with many imported videos, until I discovered that, then user import videos in FHD (video size is greater than 3000 px) AVplayer stops to work , return a black screen and doesn't react on play/stop buttons at all, and give the this error:

> "Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 "Cannot Complete Action "NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later"

After user import many videos (around 5 sometimes 8 , it is not a precise number of assets) video appear in the player but the you press play is show black screen and the error with player status .failed.

It seems more to be a memory management in AVFondation library or something like this, I don't know.

Even if I use this approach, to insert  asset key async, give the same error

```
let assetKeysToLoadAndTest: [String] = ["duration", "playable", "preferredRate", "preferredVolume", "hasProtectedContent", "providesPreciseDurationAndTiming", "metadata"]

asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: assetKeysToLoad, completion {...})
```

Honestly I try everything that I know and without success. On internet search also doesn't give very many results.

Who knows what can be the problem?

Comment: That's not how we present code here.